# How to write a Proposal on a Graphics Design bid as a newbie(in freelancer.com)?

Tags: project-bidding

I am a newbie to freelancer.in and want to bid in here.
but the main thing is that to write the proposal on the bid. i heard its the main thing that we could impress the Client. i am an UX/UI designer. can anyone one help me how to write the proposal. if possible give some sample relating to graphics design / logo design / 3d design/ web design.

Comment: This [article](http://www.ryrob.com/how-to-write-best-freelance-proposal/) can be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link provided by Mario in the comment to your question is a great link, however I would like to add something to it.

A great proposal does two things, it answers all the explicit and implied questions raised by the original bid/proposal/tender and provides the answers to the simple questions of how much will it cost, how long will it take, how will you do it and how will it solve our problem. If you can answer all that you have a great proposal.

A weak proposal leaves questions unanswered, like 'what feedback can we give?', 'how many revisions can we make?', 'what support is there for us post delivery?'.

All you can do, is to concisely address all the issues without writing a novel, and provide a mechanism to answer any further questions. As a freelancer, your ability to do this will improve with time, experience and the ability to cut and paste from one proposal to the next.

Writing a bid proposal is as personal and individual as it gets. It gives you the opportunity to shine, to stand above the rest in clarity and understanding, but offers all the risks of failing to address the underlying issues or to answer the unspoken questions. It is an art form you will master with time and practice.

A template or bland outline will help you in the early days, but as you become more proficient and expert in your field they will seem as detached and ambiguous to you as they would to a true leader or expert in their field. But if you are new to writing proposals, they will provide an invaluable guide to adhere to as you develop.

A great proposal will win you work. A poor one will lose you work. A template will help you to not lose work outright, but only time and expertise and practice will make you great. In time you will neither want, need nor look at templates for writing proposals, instead you will understand what the client is actually asking for, you will read between the lines and get to the crux of the matter at hand and write individual responses to every bid, and win a big proportion of them. If you can get there quickly, great, but in the beginning expect to write far more proposals than you win - and see every loss as a learning exercise. Ask for feedback, seek reasons for the alternate choice that was made without judgement, and very soon your proposals will be blowing people away.

For me, my best proposals have always had one key element that always hit the mark, that is understanding what the client actually wanted from often overblown or confused descriptions from amateur writers. If I had to give one piece of advice, it would be to try to understand where the client is coming from, and where they want to go. If you can nail that, you can nail the proposal.